# Unable to get triggering records in Before Insert(Fast Field Updates) and loop over them

Tags: visual-workflow, loop, insert, recordtriggeredflow, before-save-flow

I was trying by using "Get Records" elements to get all the records of the object triggering the flow. But as the record is not being inserted yet, I can't filter it via
Id.
Is there any workaround for this so that we can get all the inserted records and loop over them one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Fast Field Mode runs before the records get saved to the database you can't query that record using "Get Record of Flow".

You can handle this scenario in the following ways:

1. perform the operations on the triggering record as per your need, along with the rest of the record related to the same object by querying them using "Get Record" and performing the same operation.
2. or you can use "Actions and Related Records" mode to suffice your need as it runs in after save mode, so you would be able to get the triggering record in "Get Record" of flow along with other record of same object.

Comment: As per your first point, is this possible for multiple triggering records? I want to bulkify the flow.

Comment: yup it would be bulkify coz you are not adding any additional queries... for the existing records there is a need for query

Comment: I didn't know earlier that flow handles bulkification on its own. Thank you!